# receiving part is not working well in TCP socket programming

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, serversocket

I'm making a TCP socket programming.

**client**:
a client will receive a list of files from a server --> send a file name to the server --> receive the file from the server

My problems:

1. the server sends the list of files correctly. I printed out all and all of them are sent well. however, the client receives it well but while the loop isn't finished even if the server sending while loop is finished.

[client]

```
while ((read_cnt=read(sd, buf, BUF_SIZE)) != 0) {
    read_cnt=read(sd, buf, BUF_SIZE);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
}
```

[server]

```
while ((entry=readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
    sprintf(buf, "%s\n", entry->d_name);
    write(clnt_sd, buf, strlen(buf));
}
```

2. the server sends 17 messages but the client receives 15 messages and while loop is not finished. when while loop receives "finish", make client finishes the while loop --> still it receives 15 messages even if the server sent 17 messages.

[client]

```
while (1) {
    read_cnt=read(sd, buf, BUF_SIZE);
    fwrite((void*)buf, 1, read_cnt, fp);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    if (strstr(buf, "fin") != NULL) {
        break;  
    }
    total_read += read_cnt;
    pcnt = ((total_read/ file_size) * 100.0)/10;
    printf("(%.0d %%) Send %.0f / %.0f bytes.\n", pcnt*10, total_read, file_size);
}
```

[server]

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(file_name, "r");
    
if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("File not Exist");
    exit(1);
}

fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);    
int file_size = ftell(fp); 
sprintf(buf, "%d", file_size);
write(clnt_sd, buf, read_cnt);
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
        
while (feof(fp) == 0) {
    read_cnt = fread((void*)buf, 1, BUF_SIZE, fp);
    write(clnt_sd, buf, read_cnt);
}
fclose(fp);
```

I tried memset, bzero to make buffer empty but it didn't work.
I think the problem is the client part because when I checked server side by using print, they are sending well and finished the while loops. But I don't know what's the problem in receiving process on the client side. Please, Let me know what's the problem is.

Comment: To me this looks like C-style code compiled by a C++ compiler: in the last code snippet, you are writing `int file_size = ftell(fp);` within a code block *after* a non-declaration.

Comment: Whoever is teaching you how to get the size of a file is teaching you bad things.  You're opening the file in text mode with `fp = fopen(file_name, "r");`, and for a file in text mode [`ftell()` does not return a byte offset](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.4p2):

Comment: "For a text stream, its file position indicator contains unspecified information, usable by the fseek function for returning the file position indicator for the stream to its position at the time of the ftell call; the difference between two such return values is not necessarily a meaningful measure of the number of characters written or read."  That's enough to break things on a Windows system.

Comment: To me, this looks very much like a carelessly reformulated exam task, see for instance *`when while loop receives "finish", make client finishes the while loop`*

Comment: @Wolf Henie Thank you for your comments. my problem was receiving loop is not stopped. while ((read_cnt = read(clnt_sd, buf, BUF_SIZE))!=0) this part. ftell returned the bytes I want and I think there is no problem. However, the receiving part is not working correctly. Do you guys know how to solve it? and it's not the exam. That part is I made that to stop the while loop

Answer (score 2):

> the server sends 17 messages but the client receives 15 messages

**Completely normal.**

TCP is a stream protocol, not a message passing protocol.  What you "send" on one side may not be the exact number of bytes received at the other end.  You have to expect messages to arrive chunked, coalesced, or segmented between and within read/recv calls.  You can't even assume that the initial "size" write you send as a 4-byte message is received within the same `read` call either as an entire message.

Implement your client side code to expect `read` and `recv` to return a random number of bytes up to the size of the buffer you pass in.  If you get less bytes than expected, you need to make another `read/recv` call to receive the rest - adjusting your destination buffer pointer as needed.  Or use the `MSG_WAITALL` flag with `recv` (instead of read) to get all the data in one call.  You still need to check the result of the buffer to make sure you got the expected number of bytes, that the stream didn't close, and to validate that an error (-1 return) didn't occur.

Comment: *Or use the `MSG_WAITALL` flag with `recv` (instead of `read`) to get all the data in one call.*  That really doesn't gain anything because [it's not guaranteed to work](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/recv.html): "The function may return the smaller amount of data if the socket is a message-based socket, if a signal is caught, if the connection is terminated, if `MSG_PEEK` was specified, or if an error is pending for the socket."  Partial read results still have to be handled so the code still needs to be there.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I changed it but it didn't work. while loop is still not broken. while (1){
 read_cnt = recv(clnt_sd, buf, BUF_SIZE, MSG_WAITALL); 
 if (read_cnt < BUF_SIZE){
   fwrite(buf, read_cnt, 1, fp); 
   break;
  }
 fwrite(buf, read_cnt, 1, fp); 

 }